# Como criar efeito de fade-in em div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tenho uma `div` que recebe dados do banco MySQL e lista as imagens. Coloquei um *lightbox* para ficar mais interessante a visualização das imagens e um efeito de *fade-in* para que sempre que troque a categoria do menu*refresh* fosse dado apenas na `div` e não na página inteira. Só que quando eu tenho abrir o *lightbox* em alguma outra categoria que não seja a padrão, que exibe todos eles, não abre.

```
 <!-- Script do Fade In -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var content = $('#modal');

            //pre carregando o gif
            loading = new Image(); loading.src = 'images/loading_ajax.gif';
            $('#menu-portifolio a').live('click', function( e ){
                e.preventDefault();
                content.html( '<img src="images/loading_ajax.gif" />' );
                var href = $( this ).attr('href');
                $.ajax({
                    url: href,
                    success: function( response ){
                        //forçando o parser
                        var data = $( '<div>'+response+'</div>' ).find('#modal').html();

                        //apenas atrasando a troca, para mostrarmos o loading
                        window.setTimeout( function(){
                            content.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                                content.html( data ).fadeIn();
                            });
                        }, 500 );
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


    <!-- Script do Lightbox -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();

                var id = $(this).attr("href");

                var alturaTela = $(document).height();
                var larguraTela = $(window).width();

                //colocando o fundo preto
                $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
                $('#mascara').fadeIn(50);
                $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

                var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
                var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ( $(id).height() / 2 );

                $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
                $(id).show();  
            });

            $("#mascara").click( function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(".window").hide();
            });

                $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    $("#mascara").hide();
                    $(".window").hide();
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Os resultados da consulta SQL, no caso imagens estão sendo exibidas por categorias.

`Categoria 01` mostra apenas imagens que forem desta categoria.

Ao carregar a página ele automaticamente mostra as imagens que estejam na categoria todos.

Aí o *lightbox* funciona normal, porém ao mudar para a `Categotia 01` por exemplo o *lightbox* já não funciona mais, em nenhuma outra categoria.

Tem algum outro *script* de efeito *fade-in* pra me indicar, já que ainda sou leigo no assunto de jQuery e AJAX.

Comment: Não entendi @HermesNetto.

Comment: Oi, não da de entender o problema por favor reescreva essa parte:

"só que quando eu tenho abrir o lightbox em alguma outra categoria que não seja a padrão, que exibi todos ele não abre."

Comment: Olá, Hermes Netto. Por favor, utilize o site http://jsfiddle.net e coloque todo o código necessário para reproduzir seu problema nele, e explique o tal problema em seguida, para que possamos ajuda-lo. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu entendi seu problema, só não consigo entender essa parafernalha toda que você escreveu. Você quer clicar numa categoria e filtrar as "imagens" correspondentes, mas fazendo isso com um "efeitinho", certo?

Comment: Veja se este plugin faz algo parecido. Sempre quando uso Ligthbox eu uso ele: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Quase isso Edgar Muniz Berlinck, quando clicar na categoria eu quero que ele recarregue apenas a div, evitadando dar refresh na pagina inteira entendeu?

Comment: Eu já consegui fazer ele recarregar só a div com aquele script lá de cima, mas ele da um certo conflito com o lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $( '<div>'+response+'</div>' ).find('#modal').html();
```

Seria interessante você atribuir um 'id' ou 'class' à sua div, facilitaria sua vida (e talvez ajudaria o script) à identificar o elemento na sua página, algo como isso:

```
var data = $( '#div'+response.id ).find('#modal').html();
```

Outra coisa, supondo que para cada categoria haverá uma div[id=modal], seria interessante também trocar #modal para .modal, apenas para fins de validação de seu código html.

--
Se puder enviar o código retornado da sua requisição e o html, seria de grande ajuda pra nós e pra você. Tente o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Fiz a alteração que me falou porem agora fica carregando sem parar...

Comment: Coloque o resultado em um depurador de scripts online, como o jsfiddle. Ficaria muito mais fácil e rápido detectar e corrigir o problema.

Comment: Pra ser honesto estou tentando isso agora, mas não consegui nada ainda..

Comment: `var data = $( '#'+response.id ).find('#modal').html();` - ou o HTML está inválido ou isso é exatamente o mesmo que `var data = $('#modal').html();` - ids são únicas, ir contra isso causará bugs em alguns navegadores.

Comment: `var data = $( '#div'+response.id ).find('#modal').html();`

**Supondo que seu response.id seja 2;**

Esse código irá procurar a div "#div2" e dentro dela irá procurar o conteúdo html da div #modal.

`$('#modal').html()`
Retornará o conteúdo da div #modal, caso exista mais de uma, irá te retornar a última encontrada.